# How to pass data from controller to view using AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to show a data controller to view using ajax and I have already shown a data controller to view on the chart bar without ajax I need to get data on the chart bar using ajax but I don't have an idea how to show data on chart bar using ajax.

I don't have that good experience in JSON/AJAX/Laravel, I'm a beginner.

**Controller**

```
 public function index()
{
   
    $manager_hourlog = Hourlog::with('project', "user")->get()- 
    >groupBy('project.name');

    $projects = [];
    $totals = [];
    foreach ($manager_hourlog as $key => $val) {
        $projects[] = $key;
    }
    foreach ($manager_hourlog as $key2 => $val) {

        $minutes = $val->sum('hour_work');

        $totals[] = round($minutes / 60, 1);
    }

    $users = User::where("status", 1)->get();

    $data = [
        // manager report
        'manager_projects' => $projects,
        'totals' => $totals,
        "manager_hourlog" => $manager_hourlog,
        "auth"        => $auth,

    ];
   return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
   return view('cms.dashboard', $data);
}
```

**Script**

```
 <script>
 // Employee  report script
var colors = ["#1abc9c", "#2ecc71", "#3498db", 
"#9b59b6", "#34495e", "#16a085", "#27ae60"];
    @if ($auth->user_type != 1) 
     // manager  report script
        var managerchartbar = {
      
      
    labels: {!! json_encode($manager_projects) !!},
            datasets: [
     @foreach($users  as  $user)
        {

          label: {!! json_encode($user->name) !!},
          backgroundColor: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
          // data: [300,200,500,700]
          data: [
            @foreach($manager_hourlog as $hourlog) 
              {{$hourlog->where("user_id", $user->id)->sum("hour_work") / 60}},
            @endforeach
          ]
        },
    @endforeach
      ]

        };
  var ctx = document.getElementById('manager').getContext('2d');
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: managerchartbar,
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Employees Report chart'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });

    @endif
```

**ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{{url("/dashboard")}}',
         data: {
        data: data
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.data);

    },
    error: function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});

    </script>
```

**Html VIew**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card-box">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <canvas id="manager" height="100">
            </canvas> 
          </div>
          </br>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Route**

```
             Route::get('/dashboard', 
            'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
```

Comment: Which chart you are using ?

Comment: Dear sir, I am using a chart.org this https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked-group.html

Comment: you can use `HTML` , in your controller do all thing you need to get the chart and then in your `blade` after page loaded call that controller function with ajax and in `success` of your ajax write this code: `$("#manager").html(input_ajax_success);`

Comment: can you please explain me with my code step by step

Comment: Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/chartiq/8ybuwusL/

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.